# How to debug eloquent queries executed in Codeigniter

Tags: event-handling, eloquent, codeigniter-3

I'm using Eloquent 5.* on my CodeIgniter3.1.1 project, Everything works fine however i want to check the queries executed when a request is processed,

After some googling i came accross [Using Eloquent ORM inside CodeIgniter with added Query Logging](http://jamieonsoftware.com/post/90299647695/using-eloquent-orm-inside-codeigniter-with-added) and having CI Profiler enabled i see "No Queries Executed",

my `database.php` configuration for Eloquent looks as below

```
//Eloquent ORM database connection

use Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager as Capsule;

$capsule = new Capsule;
$capsule->addConnection(array(
'driver' => 'mysql',
 'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost; dbname=communit_iwa_test charset=utf8;',
'host' => $db['default']['hostname'],
'database' => $db['default']['database'],
'username' => $db['default']['username'],
'password' => $db['default']['password'],
'charset' => 'utf8',
'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
'prefix' => $db['default']['dbprefix'],
));
$capsule->setAsGlobal();  
$capsule->bootEloquent();


$events = new Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher;
$events->listen('illuminate.query',function($query, $bindings, $time,$name) {

// Format binding data for sql insertion

foreach ($bindings as $i => $binding) {
    if ($binding instanceof \DateTime) {
        $bindings[$i] = $binding->format('\'Y-m-d H:i:s\'');
    } else if (is_string($binding)) {
        $bindings[$i] = "'$binding'";
    }
}

// Insert bindings into query
$query = str_replace(array('%', '?'), array('%%', '%s'), $query);
$query = vsprintf($query, $bindings);

// Add it into CodeIgniter
$db = & get_instance()->db;
$db->query_times[] = $time;
$db->queries[] = $query;
});

$capsule->setEventDispatcher($events);
/* End of file database.php */
/* Location: ./application/config/database.php */
```

Your Help is appreciated in advance

Comment: Hi, I'm having the same problem, Profiler is empty for queries, did you fix it?

Comment: Use `Capsule::getQueryLog()` method to view queries executed in eloquent ORM

Comment: Yes thanks! ( As a precision, it needs Capsule::enableQueryLog() to work )

Answer (score 0):

To view executed eloquent queries use`getQueryLog()` method of the class`Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager;`

in short

1. Include `Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager` class in your controller or model as `use Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager as Capsule;`
2. use `Capsule::getQueryLog()` method to view an array of all queries executed in Eloquent ORM